# new environment with debug mode off still detects kernel.debug as true

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following new environment:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

// Use APC for autoloading to improve performance
// Change 'sf2' by the prefix you want in order to prevent key conflict with another application
/*
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('sf2', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
*/

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';
$kernel = new AppKernel('mobile', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

however when I do the following:

```
sudo php app/console assetic:dump --env=mobile
```

it gives me:

```
Clearing the cache for the mobile environment with debug true
```

How is it possible that `debug` is set to true while I have specifically in the new AppKernel('mobile' false);

I have cleared the cache and everything but it is still the same

When I do the following:

```
 $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    ladybug_dump($kernel->isDebug());
```

this returns false, however it's just the console command that is not getting it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo php app/console assetic:dump --env=dev --no-debug
```

Comment: When you give an answer it is recommended to add some explanation to your code.

Comment: You're right. A console script doesn't initialize with app.php but with app/console, which you run from the command line. You should have a look at this code and you'll understand...